# F# error FS0695, This recursive binding uses an invalid mixture of recursive forms

Tags: f#, immutability

The following code results in a compiler error, "FS0695: This recursive binding uses an invalid mixture of recursive forms."

```
type Parent =
    { ParentName : string
      Children : Child list }

and Child = 
    { ChildName : string 
      Parent : Parent }

let createChild parent childName =
    { ChildName = childName
      Parent = parent }

let createParent parentName childNames =
    let rec children = childNames |> List.map (fun childName -> createChild parent childName)
    and parent = {
        ParentName = parentName
        Children = children
    }
    parent
```

What does the error message mean? How should I correct this code?

The code is intended to initialize F# immutable records with circular references. I tried to apply the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738387/recursion-immutability-in-f) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031982/critique-of-immutable-classes-with-circular-references-design-and-better-option), but without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this error and it doesn't appear to be documented anywhere, but here's what I can surmise after playing around with it a bit.

The issue seems to be in how the `parent` is closed over by the lambda expression, which itself is inside the definition of `children`. This apparently throws off the type checker ([tc.fs](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service/blob/master/src/fsharp/tc.fs#L3492))—my guess is because the right side of the `children` binding itself contains an expression (the lambda expression) that itself contains a recursive reference, but the true cause may be more subtle than this. Notice that if you reverse the declarations like this:

```
let createParent parentName childNames =
    let rec parent = {
        ParentName = parentName
        Children = children }
    and children = childNames |> List.map (fun childName -> createChild parent childName)
    parent
```

You'll also see this warning on the line where `children` is being bound:

> Warning: This and other recursive references to the object(s) being defined will be checked for initialization-soundness at runtime through the use of a delayed reference. This is because you are defining one or more recursive objects, rather than recursive functions.

To fix this, it seems you can pull the closure out one level:

```
let createParent parentName childNames =
    let rec makeChild n = createChild parent n 
    and parent = {
        ParentName = parentName
        Children = children }
    and children = childNames |> List.map makeChild
    parent
```

Or curry the `parent` parameter into the value into `createChild` method like this (notice that `makeChild` must be declared after `parent`):

```
let createParent parentName childNames =
    let rec parent = {
        ParentName = parentName
        Children = children }
    and makeChild = createChild parent
    and children = childNames |> List.map makeChild
    parent
```

Or more simply like this:

```
let createParent parentName childNames =
    let rec parent = {
        ParentName = parentName
        Children = children }
    and children = childNames |> List.map (createChild parent)
    parent
```

Comment: Can you confirm that we must have a separate `rec` function like `makeChild`. It seems that a curried function will work too. `List.map (createChild parent)` instead of `List.map makeChild` seems to work, too, and be simpler.

Comment: @Wally Yep you're right, it seems to be an issue with how the `parent` is closed over by the lambda expression. I wasn't able to find any documentation on the error, but I was able to determine that it's thrown by the type checker ([tc.fs](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service/blob/master/src/fsharp/tc.fs#L3492)).

Comment: @Wally I've updated my answer for completeness. I've provided more detail on my research and some other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Because both sides need to be functions rather than properties

Try this instead:

```
let createParent parentName childNames =
    let rec children names =
        names |> List.map (fun childName -> createChild (parent ()) childName)
    and parent () = {
        ParentName = parentName
        Children = children childNames
    }
    parent ()
```

Comment: this would create a parent instance per child, right?

Comment: Yeah, p.s.w.g's solution is actually a lot better, I didn't realise you could bind things like that.